# What is the root of this npm err and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've been stuck with this error for a few days now and I still can't figure it out. If anyone can work it out, I would appreciate it greatly! :)

### Complete Log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~prestart: websitebackend@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: websitebackend@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program
 Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\jag01\Projects\websitebackend\node_modules.bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\jag01\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jag01\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\jag01\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\jag01\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\jag01\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\jag01\Projects\websitebackend
10 silly lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node .' ]
11 silly lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle websitebackend@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: websitebackend@1.0.0 start: `node .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid websitebackend@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\jag01\Projects\websitebackend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error websitebackend@1.0.0 start: `node .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the websitebackend@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What code or command are you running to cause this?

Comment: Thank you for a warm welcome! :) I am using javascript (on the Visual Studio Code IDE) and using nodeJS to run it.